# Unable to activate Kafka in cdh 5.7.0

Tags: apache-kafka, flume, cloudera-cdh

I am new to CDH 5.7.0. I need Kafka and flume to be used in my project. When I started Cloudera Manager, I found kafka as already available for download. I clicked on "Dowbload" to download kafka and then clicked on "Distribut" to distribute it. But When I clicked "Activate", the activation showed following error "CDH (5.2 and higher) parcel required for KAFKA (2.0.2-1.2.0.2.p0.5) is not available.". What can be the cause for this? Please help me with any suggestions. Also I need to know whether Flume is already installed in CDH 5.7.0. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory: you will need to download and activate the CDH 5.7.0 parcel as well, have you done that? Note that this requires use of Cloudera Manager 5.7.0 or later.

And yes, Flume is included in CDH.

Comment: Yes Justin. I got it. After I installed CDH5 then kafka got installed but I am unable to start kafka as a service. Its hsowing error. What can be the cause?